# How do you make a code run after a callback function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I would like to run a code after the callback function; however, because it's a callback function, the runFirst() function inside the callback function runs after the runSecond() function. Is there an easy way to remedy this?

```
$http.get($requestURL).success(function(response){

    argument = runFirst();

    });
});

runSecond(argument);
```

Comment: Use a promise in the `runFirst()` function.

Comment: Can you post a snippet?

Comment: Can you provide the code of `runFirst();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use promise chaining.

```
$http.get( 'your url' ).then(
    function( response ) {
       return runFirst();
    }
).then(
    function( argument ) {
        runSecond( argument );
    }
);
```

Comment: Can we do .success and then use .then?

Comment: Yes, success returns a promise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use promises.

```
$http.get($requestURL).then(function(response){

    argument = runFirst().then(runSecond());

    });
});
```

You just have to make sure `runFirst()` returns a promise as well.

Docs: [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)